# UIScrollView doesnt work for the subViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a view with the scrollView implemented into it and it works perfectly fine. But when I add subViews to my parent view, the scrollView works in the background i.e. the parentView and subView doesnt move it will be static. How can I make the whole view scroll?

I have added the subViews as below:

```
evfView1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EVFView"];

 evfView1.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 517, 1024, 128);

[self.view addSubview:evfView1.view];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the scroll view the superview.  Everything that is a subview of the scroll view will scroll inside of it